# Could not load requested class : org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Tags: java, hibernate, hsqldb

I'm struggling with creating connection with in-memory HSQLDB using Hibernate. It is simple log application. I did it in line with Hibernate doc and checked with other tutorials and still nothing.
I have propper dependency in my pom.xml and stilit doesn't work.

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
<session-factory>
    <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver</property>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:hsqldb:mem:logs</property>
    <property name="connection.username">sa</property>
    <property name="connection.password"></property>
    <!-- JDBC connection pool settings ... using built-in test pool -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">1</property>
    <!-- Select our SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect</property>
    <!-- Echo the SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <!-- Set the current session context -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">create-drop</property>
    <!-- dbcp connection pool configuration -->
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.initialSize">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxTotal">20</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxIdle">10</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.minIdle">5</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dbcp.maxWaitMillis">-1</property>
    <mapping class="com.analyzer.domain.Log" />
</session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

HibernateUtil.class

```
public class HibernateUtil {

private static StandardServiceRegistry registry;
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        try {
            // Create registry
            registry = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().configure().build();
           
            // Create MetadataSources
            MetadataSources sources = new MetadataSources(registry);

            // Create Metadata
            Metadata metadata = sources.getMetadataBuilder().build();

            // Create SessionFactory
            sessionFactory = metadata.getSessionFactoryBuilder().build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            if (registry != null) {
                StandardServiceRegistryBuilder.destroy(registry);
            }
        }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
  }
}
```

Output:

```
org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:237)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.id.factory.internal.DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.injectServices(DefaultIdentifierGeneratorFactory.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.injectDependencies(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:286)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:243)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.<init>(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:127)
    at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:86)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:479)
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:85)
    at com.analyzer.utility.HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:31)
    at com.analyzer.LogAnalyzerApplication.main(LogAnalyzerApplication.java:11)
Caused by: org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.spi.ClassLoadingException: Unable to load class [org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver]
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:133)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.loadDriverIfPossible(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildCreator(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:105)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.buildPool(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:89)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.configure(DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl.java:73)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.configureService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:107)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.initializeService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:246)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.getService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:214)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.buildJdbcConnectionAccess(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:146)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.internal.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.initiateService(JdbcEnvironmentInitiator.java:35)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.internal.StandardServiceRegistryImpl.initiateService(StandardServiceRegistryImpl.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.service.internal.AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.createService(AbstractServiceRegistryImpl.java:263)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Could not load requested class : org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.AggregatedClassLoader.findClass(AggregatedClassLoader.java:210)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.classForName(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:130)
    ... 25 more
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.analyzer.LogAnalyzerApplication.main(LogAnalyzerApplication.java:11)
```

Comment: It looks like you have used the wrong name for the driver class; see https://javadoc.io/doc/org.hsqldb/hsqldb/latest/org.hsqldb/org/hsqldb/jdbc/JDBCDriver.html

Comment: with org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver still the same. I've tried it before. Btw, org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver extends org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver.

Comment: If you are sure that the classname is correct, are you sure that the JAR file containing the class is on the **runtime** classpath?

Comment: Dependency in pom.xml is not enough? `<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>`

Comment: It depends on how you deploy.  But here's the thing.  If your problem is not the class name and not the classpath and the exceptions are as you have said ... then I cannot think of any other possible explanations. Hint: it is always a good idea to **check** things ... to confirm that what you think is true is actually true.

Comment: And in fact ... doesn't a `runtime` dependency mean that the Maven *won't* include the JAR in the WAR or whatever ... because it is supposed to be provided by the runtime into which you are deploying?

Comment: It's always good to check things! :) Which I'll do...